# Is there possibility in Portainer to create docker-compose yml file from running container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer

Is there possibility in Portainer to create docker-compose yml file from running container?
Or is there possibility of getting this data form docker command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.
Check out [docker-autocompose](https://github.com/Red5d/docker-autocompose)

this will spit the yml file in the console:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ghcr.io/red5d/docker-autocompose <container-name-or-id> <additional-names-or-ids>...
```

GL